# All possibilities in shadowing in nested classes

Tags: java, inner-classes

I came across below concept snippet on [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) page which explains how same named variables are shadowed inside non static/instance method of inner class instance:

```
public class ShadowTest {

    public int x = 0;

    class FirstLevel {

        public int x = 1;

        void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
            System.out.println("x = " + x);  //23
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);  //1
            System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x); //0
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ShadowTest st = new ShadowTest();
        ShadowTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
        fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);
    }
}
```

I want to highlight that here there three aspects:

1. We have created instance of `FirstLevel` inner class
2. `methodInFirstLevel` is non static
3. We are accessing

   - variable `x` local to `methodInFirstLevel`
   - `FirstLevel` instance variable `this.x`
   - `ShadowTest` instance variable `ShadowTest.this.x`

I was quick to realize there can be a lot of possibilities. For example:

1. In point 1 above, I can add:

   - We may decide to not to create instance, that is call method on class name
   - Instead of inner class (which is defined as ***non static nested class*** in same link above), we may deal with ***static nested class***.
2. In point 2 above, I can add, calling static method
3. In point three, I can add:

   - `FirstLevel` static variable
   - `ShadowTest` static variable

If you check the combinations grows quite big. I tried to figure out how the accesses will be done in all these cases. In below image, I tried to put this in somewhat structured form. I have striked through the combinations not possible given reason in red font. Also I have used class names `InnerClass`, `OuterClass`, `StaticNestedClass` for better clarity (as used on above link for other examples). `(#)` is just placeholder to let me think what type of class I am dealing with while coming up below. I have put bullets for you refer it in comments and answer. I am unsure about everything here, especially pink stuff.

This is super confusing to me, even though I have put all this effort. I want someone to confirm. Though I can code this and check every case, I am super exhausted now.

[image]

**PS:** I might be 200+% stupid in putting all these unnecessary thoughts. I could have just remembered things in above code and chilled. If that is the case please tell that too.

Answer (score 0):

Your point in recording your thoughts is legit and I suggest to create a table (or multiple tables) for a better overview.

It could look like this:

**non-static Inner Type**

```
                      |   Outer class   |   Inner class  
----------------------+-----------------+----------------
   non-static member  |  Outer.this.x   |  [this.]x
----------------------+-----------------+----------------
       static member  |  Outer.x        |  [Inner.]x
```

Note that the syntax does not depend on the enclosing method, except for that you cannot reference a non-static variable from a static method.

In lines 20 + 21 of your example you work around this by accessing the fields of arbitrary objects, which are of type `InnerClass` and `OuterClass`, respectively. The `this` keyword (and any qualifying syntax) is therefore replaced by the variable name. In a nutshell, these lines are correct, but not related to the topic.

Comment: About line 20 and 21, those variables are accessed inside static method (as can be seen in the parent node in the hierarchy at line  16), in which we cannot use `this`, the method should have been explicitly passed the object references specified `staticNestedClassObj` and `outerClassObj`.